# Why Karn Chhedan sanskar is required?

Tags: rituals, life, samskara

There are 16 sanskar in Hinduism in which 9th sanskar is Karn Chhedan. Why is it required ? I googled and found it is done for good health. Can anyone explain it logically. I don't see it relatable.

Comment: Its  sacrament and important rites with esoteric meanings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Why Karn Chhedan is  required ?**

[**Sushruta Samhita**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/sushruta-samhita-volume-1-sutrasthana/d/doc122909.html)volume 1: - Chapter XVI - **Puncturing and Bandaging the ear** - Karna-Vyadha-Vandha-Vidhi-adhyaya.Provides us some explanation.

> **The lobules of the ears of an infant are usually pierced through for protecting it (from the evil influences of malighant stars and
>   spirits) and for the purposes of ornamentation as well.** The piercing
>   should be performed on a day of bright fortnight marked by the
>   auspicious lunar and astral combinations, and in the sixth or the
>   seventh month of the year reckoned from its beginning (Bhadra). The
>   child should be placed on the lap of its nurse, and benedictions
>   should be pronounced over it. Then having soothed it and lured it with
>   toys and playthings, the physician should draw down with his left hand
>   the lobules of its ears with a view to detect, with the help of the
>   reflected sun-light, (the closed up) apertures that are naturally
>   found to exist in those localities. Then he should pierce them
>   straight through with a needle held in his right hand.